# How to embed an executable program in another as if the iframe does in HTML

Tags: visual-c++

I have an existing GUI program named A.
How can I write another program in Visual C++ which hosts A as a CView or something similar.
Just like a html inside another html using iframe.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you modify the child program?

Comment: Yes, but the child program is written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that, However you would have to provide a container control on the hosting application. I embedded Google Earth into a tracking app I was developing in C# with a similar method.

**Method**

1. Use Windows Hook to capture program "A" on process start.
2. Use spy++ to find out the window handle for "A"
3. Use SetWindowPosEx function to make your host container the parent for "A"

*NB The windows hook will be a global hook so the code has to be bullet proof, and the hooking code must reside in a .dll file.